# how to run .sql file in hive shell

Tags: hive

i was trying to run .sql file in hive shell like below. But getting the error below.

```
hive> hive -f /home/centos/DB2.sql;
NoViableAltException(24@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '-' 'f'
```

The sql file has the DDL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@anilkumar you should execute the sql command at the command prompt, not the hive> prompt.  Also remove the ; on the end of the command string.  Those are only needed at hive> prompt to suggest end of an HQL statement.   Your command is not an hql statement, your HQL is inside of the sql file.